# Coding in Perl: Finding unused variables

Tags: perl

How can I locate unused variables and/or dead code in Perl? This can easily be done in Java with an IDE. Can it be done in Perl?

This is a single stand-alone script and I will spot any variables that might be used in one of the requires.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/) is a comprehensive package for source-code standards checking. It's capable of finding unused variables and unreachable code among many other things.

Comment: comprehensive and very configurable

Comment: But also limited for the purpose of finding unused variables. From the docs: "At present, this Policy is very limited in order to ensure that there aren't any false positives. Hopefully, this will become more sophisticated soon. Right now, this only looks for simply declared, uninitialized lexical variables."

Answer (score 14):

See [warnings::unused](http://search.cpan.org/dist/warnings-unused/lib/warnings/unused.pm).

> This pragmatic module extends lexical warnings to complain about unused variables.
>
> It produces warnings when a `my` variable or `state` variable is unused aside from its declaration.

Comment: or just use warnings; will load everything

Comment: soulSurfer2010, you are mistaken. Just `use warnings;` will not load `warnings::unused`. It's a different package.

Comment: Unfortunately, it says on the page you link to: "The author no longer maintain this module. Consider Test::Vars if you detect unused vars as a unit test."